# Sqlite join two table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables: vila & tarife

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vila(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, localitate TEXT, nume_vila TEXT, detalii TEXT, nume_proprietar TEXT, nrtel INTEGER, img BLOB, im BLOB)";

db.execSQL(sql);

String tarife="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tarife(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nume_vila TEXT REFERENCES vila(nume_vila), data INTEGER, tip_camera TEXT, baie TEXT, pret INTEGER )";

db.execSQL(tarife);
```

I want to take all columns from table tarife if the nume_vila is the same in both tables.

This code does not show me anything.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tarife t LEFT JOIN vila v WHERE t.nume_vila=v.nume_vila", null);
```

Comment: Its same as that in sql.

Comment: This query works for me.